# How can I do arithmetic calculation and preserve result for next row in ng-repeat list in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one table and I want to do add/subtraction in each row and preserve the result for next row.

```
<tr ng-repeat="statement in statements.result.data">
   <td>{{statement|getClosingBalance:statements.opening_balance|number:2}}</td>
</tr>
```

Filter,

```
invoiceApp.filter('getClosingBalance', function () {
return function (statement, balance) {
    if (statement.type == 1) {
        return parseFloat(balance) + parseFloat(statement.amount);
    } else if (statement.type == 2) {
        return parseFloat(balance) - parseFloat(statement.amount);
    }
}
});
```

It is working fine as I written code,
but I want to preserve balance after each and every operations.

How can I implement the same?

Comment: can you create plunker?

Comment: this filter doesn't really make sense for this purpose.  a filter is meant to be used to return a subset of an array, or to render a data value in a specific format.  They are not meant to be used for performing functional application logic.

Comment: ok,then what will be the solution :(

Comment: Don't do that. A filter must always return the same result. It may transform a value but it mustn't change it! As usually all values are at least calculated 2 times. If the 2 values don't match angular will keep on calculate the whole app and you end up with `Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` - The solution is to calculate the values in the service - not in the HTML!

Comment: as is stated in the angular documentation for [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#!): "It is strongly discouraged to write filters that are stateful, because the execution of those can't be optimized by Angular, which often leads to performance issues."  I think the provided answer is on the right track;  If you feel that using a service to perform these calculations isn't doing what you want, you should probably open a question on that, specifically providing the code that makes that solution not work.

Comment: Thank you all for valuable point. I am moving in to service :)

Comment: reading the question again, *it seems like* you might be trying to figure out how to implement a running total, which isn't something that `ng-repeat` can be used for, since each item in an `ng-repeat` has it's own scope.

Comment: I am planning to do calculation and keeping in statements object  in controller itself quick after getting data from db. So there will not be no operation in HTML but just display whatever it is.

Answer (score 2):

why not calculate the data in a service, and keep your view clean. calculate the data in service then just render the data directly, that make your view clean and service easy to be tested.

```
   app.factory('openingBalanceService', function() {

    function calculateOpeningBalance(data){
       var result = angular.copy(data);
       /*do calculation on result*/
       return result
    }

    return{
      calculateOpeningBalance: calculateOpeningBalance
    };

   });
```

Comment: I can do in services also, but there will be two way binding.. every row updates whenever the function value updates.

Comment: so, you want your summary data to be updated whenever row updates?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing all calculation in controller itself when data received from db or api,

```
$scope.statements.balance = $scope.statements.opening_balance;
                    angular.forEach($scope.statements.result.data, function (obj) {
                        if (obj.type == 1) {
                            obj.closing_balance = parseFloat($scope.statements.balance) + parseFloat(obj.amount)
                        } else if (obj.type == 2) {
                            obj.closing_balance = parseFloat($scope.statements.balance) - parseFloat(obj.amount)
                        }
                        $scope.statements.balance = obj.closing_balance;
                    });
```

Html,

```
<td class="text-right" data-ng-bind="(company.currency)+' '+(statement.closing_balance|number:2)"></td>
```

So there will not be any kind of calcuaiton in html or inside the loop :)

Comment: I perfer to keep these kind of logic into service, keep controller as thin as possible, but it looks like ok :)